# Selenium 2 Firefox Profile Change Location

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-firefoxdriver, remotewebdriver

For many weeks now, I have been looking around and I have not seen anything regards to changing the location the Firefox Profile saves to.

I am using a specific Firefox profile, however, when the tests run the session is created in /tmp/. I would like the session to start up in a different location and save the files it uses in a location like: /var/tmp/. Is there any way to do this?

Note: This is not a question as to where I get the RemoteWebDriver to use a specific Firefox profile.

Edit: I am using Selenium 2.28 and Firefox 15.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [`FirefoxProfile:442`](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.java#442)

```
File profileDir = TemporaryFilesystem.getDefaultTmpFS()
          .createTempDir("anonymous", "webdriver-profile");
copyModel(model, profileDir);
```

The [`TemporaryFilesystem`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/io/TemporaryFilesystem.html) takes [it's location from `"java.io.tmpdir"`:](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/io/TemporaryFilesystem.java#40), which usually points to system's temp directory. Santoshsarma's solution will work because of this line (but it will also move your OS temp directory).

```
private static File sysTemp = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
```

We can do more! Look at the [*public*](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/io/TemporaryFilesystem.html#setTemporaryDirectory%28java.io.File%29) method [`setTemporaryDirectory`](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/io/TemporaryFilesystem.java#47)!

You can invoke this method just before instantiating your `FirefoxDriver` and it should create it's profile copy at the location you specified.

Answer (score 0):

**Firefox uses the OS temp file location for storing temporary files**

You need to change the location of the temp files in Windows in the control Panel if you want to use another location for temp files.

You can change the %TEMP% and %TMP% environment variables and make them point to a temp folder that you want to use.

```
Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment variables
```

Refer : [Firefox Support](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions)

Comment: While the statements are true and your advice could help, it's for a completely different reason. WebDriver makes a temp copy of the firefox profile you're working with - and saves that into the system temp dir.