# How to set the tmp directory for selenium-server-standalone

Tags: linux, selenium, selenium-server

I am running a `selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar` on a Linux VM for running selenium tests in a headless way (xvfb + firefox).

While running, the Selenium server creates a lot of temporary directories and files in `/tmp/` which are not deleted after the tests are finished.

The problem is that my /tmp/ disk is rather small and I would like to use `/var/tmp` for this purpose. However, I cannot find any way to do so.

Do you know a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium uses the JVM `java.io.tmpdir` property for this:

`java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/io/TemporaryFilesystem.java:`

```java
  private static File sysTemp = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
  private static TemporaryFilesystem instance = new TemporaryFilesystem(sysTemp);
```

Set it by passing `-Djava.io.tmpdir` to the JVM, e.g.:

```
$ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-*.jar -Djava.io.tmpdir=/some/other/tmp
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924136/environment-variable-to-control-java-io-tmpdir) has more details about `java.io.tmpdir`

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124772/selenium-2-firefox-profile-change-location) contains the answer as well, but i think the question title makes it hard to find.